# Mavericks: User no longer owner of Home folder and content

Tags: macos, permission, user-account, acl

One of the Users (called: The_Problematic_User) of a Mavericks installed MacBook Pro is no longer owner of the Home folder and content. Here's what we've tried to no avail:

- restart computer and log in recovery mode (Command-r) and;

  - repair disk permissions,
  - repair disk,
  - with resetpassword (command line),
  - reset Home Folder Permissions and  ACLs,
  - reset password,
- restart computer and log in single user mode (Command-s which is root access) and;

  - Strip ACLs on all account items with: chmod -RN /Users/username
  - response: chmod: Failed to clear ACL on file ...
  - Try to regain ownership of files and folders with: chown -R username:staff /Users/username
  - response: chown: username: illegal user name (where username was the user name of the user, obviously)
  - Try to assign ownership of files to root with: chown -R root:staff /Users/username
  - response: chown: /Users/username/*: Read-only file system (where * represents all the files and folders in the directory)

Another thing: when I ls -l /Users here is what I get:

- drwxrwxrwt  6  root wheel 204  Feb 24 10:53 Shared
- drwxr-xr-x+ 12 501  staff 408  Mar 21 17:16 A_user (with admin privileges)
- drwxr-xr-x@ 47 502  staff 1598 Mar 15 12:03 The_Problematic_User
- drwxr-xr-x+ 24 505  staff 816  Jan 10 15:11 Another_user

What is the @ doing instead of the + in the permissions of The_Problematic_User?

For info: The_Problematic_User does NOT have admin privileges

Comment: In single-user mode, you need to use `mount -uw /` to get write access to the volume, and also refer to users by ID number since names aren't available. Check the user ID number with `id "The_Problematic_User"`. Also, use `ls -leO@ /Users` to get a more complete view of the access controls and xattrs attached to the home folder.

Answer (score 2):

An erroneous extended attribute has been applied to this directory somehow, but it can only be removed using the `xattr` Terminal command. You should take a look at a brief explanation [here](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/os-x-extended-attibutes/).  A more detailed question and answer can be found at this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833052/how-do-i-remove-the-extended-attributes-on-a-file-in-mac-osx) page.